# How to validate website field in contact form 7?

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7

Is there any way to validate website field entered is right or wrong through Contact form 7?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add your own custom validation.
More info [here](https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/).

---

Here's a working and tested example for your situation:

Use `[text* your-website]` inside your contact form 7 form.

Add this snippet to your theme's functions.php, use a [child-theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)!

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_website_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
function custom_website_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
  if ( $tag->name == 'your-website' ) {

    $domain = isset( $_POST['your-website'] ) ? trim( $_POST['your-website'] ) : '';

    if ( ! checkdnsrr($domain, 'ANY') ) { // Check DNS records corresponding to a given Internet host name or IP address
      $result->invalidate( $tag, "We cannot find an active dns record for that website url?" );
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```